# Remove line with a matching word in pipe

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I'm using xlsxgrep in a pipe but there is a warning that goes in the stdout instead of ignored. I want to learn how to remove that line in the pipe itself.

My command:

```
$ xlsxgrep -riH "${SEARCHTERM}" "${DIR}" >> "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output.txt"
$ awk -F: '{print "\x27"$1"\x27"}' "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output.txt" |
    awk '!x[$0]++' |
    tee "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output-filename.txt" |
    xargs -I {} cp --backup=t {} "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output/"
```

The error lines in the pipe:

```
WARNING *** file size (36373) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
```

I had to idea to remove the 2 lines with sed matching on "WARNING ***"
Using the following command:

```
$ sed '/^WARNING \*\*\*/d' "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output.txt"
```

OUTPUT:

```
'test.xlsx'
'test2.xlsx'
```

But when I add the same command in the pipe it doesn't work

```
$ awk -F: '{print "\x27"$1"\x27"}' "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output.txt" |
    awk '!x[$0]++' |
    sed '/^WARNING \*\*\*/d'
```

OUTPUT:

```
'test.xlsx'
'WARNING *** file size (36373) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)'
'WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero'
'test2.xlsx'
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
'test.xlsx'
'test2.xlsx'
```

Why don't my commands work what's the right way?

Comment: Which command is giving the warning messages? I assume `xlsxgrep`, right? Does `sed '/^WARNING \**/d'` remove them?

Comment: Yes xlsxgrep. No, it does not remove the lines when I add when I run it like this: awk -F: '{print "\x27"$1"\x27"}' "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/xlsxgrep-output.txt" |
    awk '!x[$0]++' |
    sed '/^WARNING \**/d'

Comment: Yes, but does it remove it when you run the command I gave?

Comment: But did you use `sed '/^WARNING \**/d'` as I suggested or `sed '/^WARNING **/d'` as in your comment?

Comment: `sed '/^WARNING \**/d' input.txt` removes the lines when I run the command itself, but the command doesn't work when I pipe it

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question and clarify what is actually happening. Ideally, give us an example input file, and see how far you can simplify your pipe while still reproducing the error so we don't need to deal with so many variables. Make sure you are ***escaping*** the `*` characters as `\*` and, if you are, update your question to make that clear. Also, your `awk` seems to be inserting `'` characters at the beginning of each line which means that the string `WARNING` is now no longer at the beginning which would also explain why your sed is failing.

Comment: Regarding the `\x27s`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote for why those should be `\047`s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that these warnings are printed to stdout and not stderr, but I have no experience with this `xlsgrep` tool so I don't know if that's expected or if it maybe has an option that controls it.

In any case, your `sed` is failing because `*` is a special character in regular expressions: it means "0 or more repetitions of the previous character". In your case, you have the `*` just after a space, so  `*` means "0 or more spaces". I am not sure what the subsequent `*` are interpreted as, GNU `sed` would error out, but busybox `sed` seems to treat it as a single `*`.

In any case, the right way of doing this is escaping the `*`:

```
sed '/^WARNING \*\*\*/d'
```

Also, note that your `awk` command is inserting `'` characters at the beginning of the line:

```
awk -F: '{print "\x27"$1"\x27"}'
```

This means that `WARNING` will no longer be the first thing on the line:

```
$ echo WARNING | awk -F: '{print "\x27"$1"\x27"}' 
'WARNING'
```

You now have `'WARNING'`. So you need to take that into account in the `sed` too, by matching any character:

```
sed '/^.WARNING \*\*\*/d'
```

Or by matching single quotes:

```
sed "/^'WARNING \*\*\*/d"
```

Or maybe something else, depending on what the original input was, and what `awk` took as `$1` in `'{print "\x27"$1"\x27"}'`.

Comment: Most errors are printed stderr. This one is a bug which I reported. Yes, I know how to remove the matching word with sed. But when i add the same sed command to the pipe it doesn't work. That was the reason I'm asking this question. I'm curious why

Comment: @pwrsheller you didn't try this in your question, the command in your question would only match `WARNING` followed by many spaces, not by `*`. In addition, your `awk` is adding quotes, see updated answer.

Comment: I update my question but sed "/^'WARNING \*\*\*/d" works ty

Comment: @pwrsheller no, `sed "/^'WARNING ***/d"` only _appears_ to work. That will just delete all lines that start with `'WARNING`, even if not followed by `***`. So it would delete `'WARNING 1` or anything else. It just _also_ deletes lines starting with `'WARNING ***`.

Comment: It might also not delete any lines at all or do anything else depending on how whatever sed you're using decides to interpret `***` since it's undefined behavior (back to back repetition metachars).